# Cannot process argument transformation on parameter error while calling function in powershell

Tags: xml, function, powershell, parameter-passing

I have a powershell script in which I am generating xml file.

My script is as below:

```
$filePath= "C:\Powershell\Report.xml"
if(Test-Path $filePath)
{
    Remove-Item $filePath
} 

#set encoding
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

# Create The Document
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($filePath,$encoding)

# Set The Formatting
$xmlWriter.Formatting = "Indented"
$xmlWriter.Indentation = "4"

# Write the XML Decleration
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

SetNamespace($xmlWriter)

# Write Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement($RootElement)

#set Root Element namespaces
SetRootElementNamespace($xmlWriter)

#Create <my:PruefAuftragHeader>

$Ablagenummer = "234"
$Beschrieb = "This is testing"
$Auftraggeber = @("ADAMS","Alu König Stahl","Caradon")

CreatePruefAuftragHeader($xmlWriter ,$Ablagenummer)



Function CreatePruefAuftragHeader([System.Xml.XmlTextWriter] $xmlWriter ,[String] $Ablagenummer)
{
    $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement($PruefAuftragHeaderElement) # opening <my:PruefAuftragHeader>

    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString($AblagenummerElement,$Ablagenummer)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString($BeschriebElement,$Beschrieb)

    foreach($elem in $Auftraggeber)
    {
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString($AuftraggeberElement,$elem)
    }

    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement #closing <my:PruefAuftragHeader>
}
```

When execution reaches at line : `CreatePruefAuftragHeader($xmlWriter ,$Ablagenummer)` it throws an error : `Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'xmlWriter'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type 
"System.Xml.XmlTextWriter".`

What should I do to tackle the error?

Answer (score 2):

If you call the script like this:

```
CreatePruefAuftragHeader($xmlWriter ,$Ablagenummer)
```

you are passing the first argument as an array type

you have to call it like this:

```
CreatePruefAuftragHeader $xmlWriter $Ablagenummer
```

In powershell argument for script/function are passed separed by space and not enclosed in `()`.